# Deploy jar on openstack cirros instance

Tags: jar, openstack, devstack

It sounds very basic but I haven't found clear instructions on how to do this. I'm new on openstack. I have setted up devstack on my laptop, I have created an instance from a cirros image and now I would like this image to run a jar. I was expecting this to work in a similar way as Amazon EMR for instance, but obviously it doesn't. Any help or hints for straightforward tutorials will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cirros` image doesn't include Java nor does it include a facility for installing additional packages.  You should boot using a full distribution of some sort (e.g., Fedora, CentOS, Ubuntu, etc), and then proceed to install Java following instruction appropriate for that distribution.

Once you have Java installed, you can install and run your jar file.